# Windows Batch Call Command not passing variable value?

Tags: windows, batch, script, call

I'm getting strange output when running my script:

```
@echo off
setlocal
pushd "%~dp0"

set Mode=batch

if "%Mode%"=="batch" call :BATCH
echo %Loc%
pause>nul
exit

:BATCH
set "psCommand="(new-object -COM 'Shell.Application')^
.BrowseForFolder(0,'Please choose a folder.',0,0).self.path""
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%I in (`powershell %psCommand%`) do set "folder=%%I"
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set Loc=!folder!
Goto:eof
```

It should be displaying the folder location I select.
instead I get echo is off.

Answer (score 0):

#### I'm getting strange output when running my script

To debug your batch scripts comment the `@echo off` line so you can see what is happening:

```
rem @echo off
```

Your `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` is in the wrong place. Move it to the beginning of the file.

test.cmd:

```
@echo off
setlocal
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
pushd "%~dp0"

set Mode=batch

if "%Mode%"=="batch" call :BATCH
echo %Loc%
pause>nul

:BATCH
set "psCommand="(new-object -COM 'Shell.Application')^
.BrowseForFolder(0,'Please choose a folder.',0,0).self.path""
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%I in (`powershell %psCommand%`) do set "folder=%%I"
set Loc=!folder!
Goto:eof
```

Example output (I selected "Desktop"):

```
F:\test>test
C:\Users\DavidPostill\Desktop

F:\test>
```

Note:

- You will still get `ECHO is off.` displayed if you press "Cancel" the first time your dialog is displayed.